# GAE: Do puts and gets inside a cross group transaction (XG) need to be called with the transaction as parameter?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I've just noticed that the [docs' example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions#Java_Using_transactions) for XG transactions uses the put method that includes the transaction as a parameter, but it doesn't mention a necessity for doing it that way.

```
TransactionOptions options = TransactionOptions.Builder.withXG(true);
Transaction txn = datastore.beginTransaction(options);

Entity a = new Entity("A");
a.setProperty("a", 22);
datastore.put(txn, a);

Entity b = new Entity("B");
b.setProperty("b", 11);
datastore.put(txn, b);

txn.commit();
```

According to the [API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService#put%28com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Transaction,%20com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity%29) the single parameter put (and get) uses a transaction:

> If there is a current transaction, this operation will execute within
>   that transaction

My concern is with XG transactions. If I just use in that example the single parameter put for both entities (and I have a lot of code like that), will they both still be executed inside the XG transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they will both still be executing in the XG transaction.

If you do not explicitly specify the transaction, the most recently created transaction will be used. The `DatastoreService` stores a stack of the transactions created with `beginTransaction` and uses the top one whenever performing puts without an explicit transaction. It does not treat your XG transaction any differently, it will simply pull it off the stack and use it.